# htaccess subdomain as get with variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am trying to make like this.

```
user.mydomain.com -> mydomain.com/user.php?user=user
user.mydomain.com/content_(.*).xhtml -> mydomain.com/user.php?user=user&content=(.*)
user.mydomain.com/content_(.*).xhtml?get=(.*) ->mydomain.com/user.php?user=user&content=(.*)&get=(.*)
```

I already tried this

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

RewriteEngine On


# host doesn't start with www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.  [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m\.  [NC]

# host starts with something else
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^\.]+)\.mydomain\.com$  [NC]

# rewrite
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ users.php?user=%1  
RewriteRule ^users\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^content_(.*).xhtml$ users.php?user=%1&content=$1 [L,QSA] 
</Directory>
```

but it only passing the subdomain not the content parameters value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code in your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^users\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|m)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /users.php?user=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(?:www|m)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.mydomain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^content_([^.]+)\.xhtml$ /users.php?user=%1&content=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```